# How to solve problem regarding PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintService() in windows 

Tags: java, printing

Following is the code when I run on Linux,detects my printer and gives me print out.but when I run it on windows.It do not detect my printer.

```
printbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            DocFlavor docflavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8;

            PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

            attr_set.add(new Copies(1));

            PrintService[] service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

             if (service.length==0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Printer Selected");
                }

            else if (service.length > 0) {
                System.out.println("Selected printer is " + service[0].getName());

                    DocPrintJob pj = service[0].createPrintJob();
                    {
                        PrintService ps = pj.getPrintService();
                        FileInputStream fis = null;
                        try {
                            File file = new File("c:\\NewFile.txt");
                            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, docflavor, null);
                            pj.print(doc, attr_set);
                        } catch (PrintException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(PrintButtonView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(PrintButtonView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                fis.close();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(PrintButtonView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    });

}
```

Comment: It's probably worthwhile reducing the above to just the bit of code causing you the problem, rather than including *all* your event handler code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a security manager installed, and the correct permissions ? From the [doc](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html):

> A PrintServiceLookup implementor is
>   recommended to check for the
>   SecurityManager.checkPrintJobAccess()
>   to deny access to untrusted code.
>   Following this recommended policy
>   means that untrusted code may not be
>   able to locate any print services.
>   Downloaded applets are the most common
>   example of untrusted code.
>
> This check is made on a per lookup
>   service basis to allow flexibility in
>   the policy to reflect the needs of
>   different lookup services.
>
> Services which are registered by
>   registerService(PrintService) will not
>   be included in lookup results if a
>   security manager is installed and its
>   checkPrintJobAccess() method denies
>   access.